# matrix cxr * vector c VS vector r * matrix cxr

Tags: math, matrix, vector

I wanted to know if multiplying a matrix and a vector always gives the same result even if the vector is on the left or the right side.

> matrix cxr * vector c == vector r * matrix cxr

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Excellent question! But the most exciting way to answer  it  isto try it!! Take  a 2 2 matrix, suchas [[1,2],[3,4]],andtakea vector,  such as [10,11],  and compute  the twomultiplications  by hand!!

Comment: So, did you try it? What is the result of row_vector([10,11]) times matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])? And what is the result of matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]) times column_vector([10,11])?